# How to create a raw array in hexmode

Tags: arrays, r, hex

I need to create a array with raw type in hexadecimal form..

For example, if we have a array like c("f2","4d"......), how to convert it into raw type in hexadecimal form.

Or, do we have some methods to create a array with value: RAW [1:3] f2 4d 79
without transferring from a array of int or char?

Comment: `as.raw(as.hexmode(c("f2","4d")))` ?

Comment: btw, could you tell me how did you learned R? I am a beginner, need suggestions

Comment: Trial and error mostly! Reading stackoverflow, reading the official intro manuals, and http://statmethods.net/ were good starting points otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
as.raw(strtoi(c("f2", "4d", "79"), 16L))
```